# How to create a time-lapse animation of my data in Google Earth Studio?

Tags: timelapse, google-earth-studio

I have a kmz file of color-coded point data (of percentages) I'd like to show over time (by year) in Google Earth Studio. Anyone know how to do this?

Data looks like this (percent_empty goes from 0% ->100%):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth Studio doesn't seem to have that feature. Only thing you can do is animate time of day (position of sun). However the desktop application Google Earth Pro should let you do this.

Another solution you might do is separate the the points into different KML files each, then import all of them into Google Earth Studio and by using Keyframe Opacity you can animate them.